# Pattern match in next line and replace using sed

Tags: sed

I have file containing following data

cat file:

```
ABC
+123
+456
XYZ
+789
```

I want to search "+" at start of next line and remove "+" and concatenate with  current line

Output should be :

```
ABC 123 456
XYZ 789
```

Comment: Do you have a bit more information on what OS you're using, and which program?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### About `sed`

> I want to search "+" at start of next line and remove "+" and concatenate with current line

If you want to use `sed` then the above is not a good representation of what you want to do. In `sed` you cannot examine the next line until you read it, but then it is already the current line.

In `sed` you operate on the *pattern space*, usually the current line appears in it. There's also the *hold space* where you can hold previous line(s).

You wrote "next line", "current line". IMO it's better to think in terms of "current line" and "previous line(s)" respectively.

---

#### Mediocre solution

The below code works, you can describe it as a bunch of ifs.

```
sed -n '
1  { $ {p;q}
     h
   }
1! { /^+/  H
     /^+/! {x;s/\n+/ /g;p}
   }
$  { g;s/\n+/ /g;p
   }
'
```

At first, if we're at the first line (`1`) and it happens to be the last line (`$`), we simply `p`rint and `q`uit. If the first line is not the last line, we `h`old it in the hold space.

For every line that is not the first line (`1!`) we check if it starts with `+`. If so (`/^+/`), we append it to the hold space (`H`); this way the hold space accumulates lines. If the line does not start with `+` (`/^+/!`), we e`x`change the content of the hold and pattern spaces, so the current line alone gets stored in the hold space and previously held line(s) are ready to be operated on in the pattern space. We search (`s`) all (`g`) occurrences of newline followed by `+` (`\n+`) and replace each with one space ( ). Finally we `p`rint the result.

After this, if it's the last line (`$`) then there is something in the hold space not-yet-printed (from `H` or `x`). We `g`et it to the pattern space and proceed like before to print it as one line.

`-n` makes `sed` not print by default. Our code prints only when we explicitly use `p`.

---

#### Better solution

For what you want to do and for similar tasks, there is a clever scheme of `N`, `P`, `D`. The scheme does not use the hold space at all. It works without `-n`.

```
sed ':start;N;s/\n+/ /;t start;P;D'
```

`:` denotes a label and `start` is an arbitrary name. `N` appends the next line of input into the pattern space. Then `s` tries to replace a newline followed by `+` with a space; this will only work if the newly appended line starts with `+`. Iff `s` works then `t start` will jump to `:start`, so `N` will append yet another line and so on. This way the pattern space accumulates exactly what you need, converting one <newline>`+` at a time, until there comes a line that doesn't start with `+` and therefore `s` finds no match for `\n+`.

After `s` finds no match for `\n+`, `t` does not jump, `P` is executed. `P` prints the pattern space up to the first embedded newline. This is exactly the accumulated data from before the latest `N` that appended the line not beginning with `+`. Next `D` removes what has just been printed and starts a new cycle without reading a new line of input. Not-yet-printed text (i.e. the line not beginning with `+`) survives in the pattern space and `N` can append to it.

Note the code is very simple. Previously (in the mediocre solution) we needed a special case for the first line, another for the last line. Here `N`, `P`, `D` and the default rules of printing (i.e. the lack of `-n`) do the job naturally. They are perfect for what you want to do.

---

#### Note

Both solutions keep the first line intact, even if it starts with `+`.

Comment: Thank you **Better solution** and **Mediocre solution** for solution.
It is really well explained. :)