# Replacing double new-line in multiple files

Tags: text-editing, perl

I do a lot of text cleanup with (example) `perl -p -i -e 's:old:new:g;' *.txt` but when old is `\n\n` and new is `\n</p><p>\n`, nothing changes.  Tried escaping the angle brackets, but that didn't help.

A tolerable alternative is `perl -p -i -e 's:(.*):<p>\1</p>:g;' s:<p></p>::g;` *.txt` but it would be nice to have the tags on the blank line between the text.

Doesn't have to be perl, but most other languages I'm familiar with require compile and link.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
sed '1 N
:start;N;s#\n\n#\n</p><p>\n#;t start;P;D'
```

The "NPD" scheme is explained near the end of [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1729154/432690). In your case we need to work with 3-line window instead of 2-line window, hence additional `N` just after we read the `1`st line.

Notes:

- Use [`-i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/108618) if you want. The code may be like:

  ```
  sed -i.bak '…
  …' *.txt
  ```
- [In *nix, there should be a newline at the end of any non-empty text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743/108618). Since the pattern space in `sed` does not contain the trailing newline, in our "NPD" scheme newlines can occur only in the middle of the 3-line window we're using. This means if there are two newlines at the very end of the file then they wont be replaced. In other words the very last newline character cannot be matched literally.

---

#### Example

Input:

```
1
2
3

4


5
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
</p><p>
4
</p><p>
</p><p>
5
```

Comment: Thanks.  The last line is not important because all the files need proofreading for details that can't be automated.  (Like "their" for "there")

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to match empty lines & put in some tags there.

Then this will work :

`perl -p -i -e 's:^$:</p><p>:g;' *.txt`

If you even want to match empty lines with whitespaces, you can put that between `^$` with no other change.

Comment: This looks like the simplest of the three suggestions.  (But all three may be useful in the future.) I've already used my "alternative" on the set of files, but as soon as I have a new set, I'll try all three suggestions before checking off one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your one-liner

```perl
perl -p -i -e 's:\n\n:\n</p><p>\n:g;' *.txt
```

reads one line at a time then it never finds 2 linebreak in a single line.

You have to activate the "slurp mode" i.e. redefine the record separator.
Usually we use `undef $/;` or, in a one-liner the option `-0777`

Then your one-liner becomes:

```perl
perl -0777 -i.back -pe 's:(?<=\n)(?=\n):</p><p>:g' *.txt`
```

Comment: Thanks!  Another answer looks simpler but I haven't tested it yet.  Even if I don't use "slurp mode" on this project, it may well become useful in the future.